# Mostrar datos en exploraciones de Analytics (GA4) con estructura personalizada

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, informes

Tengo varios enlaces programados con el evento onclick en algunos módulos de mi página, utilizando gtag para analytics GA4, con la siguiente estructura:

```
gtag('event','Clic_Modulos',{'event_category': 'URL Custom','event_label': 'ABC'});
```

Donde `event_label` puede tener distintos valores, los cuales son los que necesito cuantificar (actualmente en la consulta en tiempo real sí me muestra los datos correctamente).

Sin embargo, al crear las exploraciones definiendo segmentos y dimensiones personalizadas, no lo tengo muy claro y no he podido llegar más allá del conteo de "Clic_Modulos", es decir, la agrupación de valores llega hasta ese nivel.  Alguien conoce cómo puedo llegar correctamente hasta el `event_label` ?

Saludos y gracias de antemano